# Why is the equilibrium constant being calculated differently here?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetics, nmr-spectroscopy

In my NMR textbook, it says the equilibrium constant for a dynamic process (e.g., A in equilibrium with B) is calculated by the concentration of A divided by the concentration of B.  Is this a typo?  I thought the equilibrium constant was products over reactants.

Comment: Unless they mentioned with referencen to the reverse reaction, it is a typo.

Comment: Can you add a ref to the statement?

Comment: What is the exact wording in the book?

Comment: "Up until now we have assumed that the two isomers I and II which are in dynamic equilibrium have equal energies. If this is not the case, the equilibrium mixture contains different amounts of I and II. The equilibrium constant K is then calculated from Equation (11-9), the relative concentrations of I and II being in most cases easily determined by integration of the corresponding NMR signals"  Equation 11-9: K=[I]/[II]

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of definition, really.  Equilibrium implies a reversible reaction, thus the same reaction could he rendered as $\ce{A<=>B}$ or$\ce{B<=>A}$.  So we can render the equilibrium constant as $[\ce{B}]/[\ce{A}]$ or as $[\ce{A}]/[\ce{B}]$.  We need to define which is used, of course, when we give a numerical value.